# Can I buy online train tickets from Copenhagen to Odense and print them myself?

Tags: trains, tickets, online-resources, denmark

I am travelling on business to Copenhagen at the end of the month and will visit Odense as well. I am planning to reach Odense by train and therefore want to purchase the train tickets online beforehand and print them as soon as I get to Copenhagen. I would also like to book my seat in advance with a table in front of it.

I have visited several sites where they let you purchase the tickets but courier them out to you or give you the option to purchase them through your smartphone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure which sites you have tried, but if you buy your ticket directly from the [Danish Railways](http://www.dsb.dk/en/#open), you seem to get everything you want:

- If you order a seat reservation, you can also select exactly which seat you want. You will be shown a drawing of the carriage, so that you can see where the tables are and which seats are free.
- You can have the ticket sent to an e-mail address, or also get a reservation code to pickup your ticket at a DSB ticket counter or one of their ticket machines in Copenhagen.